# Why won't Trim Substring & Non-captures work?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to capture the middle row of the following html text area:

```js
function RunClean() 
 {
        var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
        var input = input.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
        var input = input.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
        var string =  input.match("In the Matter of(.|\n)*Respondent");
       var parties = string.slice(16, -10);
     alert(parties); 
 }
```

```html
<form>
    <textarea id="input" rows="4" cols="50">
        In the Matter of
        Name I. Want,
        Respondent.
    </textarea>
    <button onclick="RunClean()">Clean</button>
</form>
```

For some reason, this wont work. It simply returns nothing.  What is going wrong, and how could I achieve this result by using regex non capture groups?

Comment: Have you tried outputting your variables along the way?  Your `string` array doesn't have many elements, and your `string.slice()` appears to be the issue.

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match newline characters (`/\n/`) you probably shouldn't remove them.

> What is going wrong [...]?

- [`input.match(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) does not return a string. It returns an array of strings.
- Your group captures a single character (either an arbitrary normal character (`/./`) or a newline (`/\n/`)), not a series of characters. (The repetition with `*` is outside the group)

> [...] and how could I achieve this result by using regex non capture groups?

Make your existing group a non-capturing group and put a capturing group around the repetition:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
var input = input.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
var matches =  input.match(/In the Matter of((?:.|\n)*)Respondent/);
var parties = matches[1];
alert(parties);
```

```js
function RunClean() 
 {
        var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
        var input = input.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
        var matches =  input.match(/In the Matter of((?:.|\n)*)Respondent/);
        var parties = matches[1];
     alert(parties); 
 }
```

```html
<form>
    <textarea id="input" rows="4" cols="50">
        In the Matter of
        Name I. Want,
        Respondent.
    </textarea>
    <button onclick="RunClean()">Clean</button>
</form>
```

Though, with all of your whitespace removal, you won't need the inner, noncapturing group at all:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
var input = input.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
var input = input.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
var matches =  input.match("In the Matter of(.*)Respondent");
var parties = matches[1];
alert(parties);
```

```js
function RunClean() 
 {
        var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
        var input = input.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
        var input = input.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
        var matches =  input.match("In the Matter of(.*)Respondent");
        var parties = matches[1];
     alert(parties); 
 }
```

```html
<form>
    <textarea id="input" rows="4" cols="50">
        In the Matter of
        Name I. Want,
        Respondent.
    </textarea>
    <button onclick="RunClean()">Clean</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is too complicated for such simple task

```
function RunClean() 
{
    alert(document.getElementById('input').value.split('\n')[1].trim());
}
```

Comment: This is jquery and not native javascript

Comment: @TiredofGoogling ok I will re-write to javascript